# form_set_error not working in node form validation

Tags: 7, forms

I'm frustrated right now. This very reduced module code shows the problem:

```
<?php

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ('pic_node_form' == $form_id && !path_is_admin(current_path()) ) {
    $form['#validate'][] = '_mymodule_pic_add_form_validate';
  }
}

function _mymodule_pic_add_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  form_set_error(null, t('Keep calm bro'));
  // die("foo");
}

function mymodule_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) {
  form_set_error(null, 'test');
  // die("bar");
}
```

`pic_node_form` is the node add form for the content type pic. That form is exposed (hence `&& !path_is_admin(current_path())`). There is an image upload field involved.

The `form_set_error` doesnt do anything and nodes keep getting submitted. The `die()` functions actually work when I remove the `//`, so the functions do get invoked.

The form itself is placed via block:

```
function _mymodule_get_block_content($delta) {
  if ('pic_add_form' == $delta) {
    global $user;
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $node = (object) array(
      'uid' => $user->uid,
      'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
      'type' => 'pic',
      'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
    );
    $form = drupal_get_form('pic_node_form', $node);
    $form_rendered = drupal_render($form);
    $markup .= $form_rendered;

    return $markup;
  }
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I guess that you have to set the `$name` (first) argument of the [form_set_error](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) function to a field name instead to `null`.

Comment: @mchar post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you have to set the `$name` (first) argument of the [form_set_error](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) function to a field name instead to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [source](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) of `form_set_error()`, you will see that if you don't supply the name of the form element for which you are setting the error, error messages will not be set.

As long as the first argument is `NULL`, form will be submitted. Your code was being executed, but it didn't stop the submission.

What you need to do is to pass the name of the field for which you want the error to show. This goes as the first argument for `form_set_error()`.

Example:

```
form_set_error('YOUR_FIELD_NAME', t('Your message'));
```

Comment: i feel so dumb right now :) still, I dont think this is nicely solved by Drupal